# 'JPEG compression requires 8-bit, 1/3-channel images' error since Fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I developed an application based on the old RVIZ (wxWidgets) and I have a tool that takes an OgreImage (from a video feed) and publishes on a different topic as a screenshot. I use a standard image_transport publisher.

In Diamondback, the listener could choose between raw, compressed, and theora. In Fuerte, only raw works.

On the publisher side, I get the following error with compressed: Compressed Image Transport - JPEG compression requires 8-bit, 1/3-channel images (input format is: rgba8)

I'm wondering if some format support was removed in Fuerte, since this used to work. Here is my code:

```
void PhotoTool::publishImageToROS(const Ogre::Image& ogreImage, const std::string& referenceFrame)
            {
                sensor_msgs::Image rosImage;

                static int seq = 0;

                rosImage.header.seq = seq++;
                rosImage.header.frame_id = referenceFrame;
                rosImage.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
                rosImage.height = ogreImage.getHeight();
                rosImage.width = ogreImage.getWidth();
                rosImage.encoding = "rgba8";
                rosImage.is_bigendian = false;
                rosImage.step = ogreImage.getRowSpan();
                size_t size = rosImage.step * rosImage.height;
                rosImage.data.resize(size);

                // Copies the data from the Ogre Image to the ROS Image
                memcpy((char*) (&rosImage.data[0]), ogreImage.getData(), size);

                publisher.publish(rosImage);
            }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47586/%27jpeg-compression-requires-8-bit,-1/3-channel-images%27-error-since-fuerte/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This bug has been fixed in:
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/commit/283c555b0f87085ca9f74790eba474b4456ed9b8

---

Originally posted by [jkammerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3073/jkammerl/) with karma: 146 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-04-04**:
Sorry that it took me so long to test it, but the problem is fixed now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a little surprised that ever worked. JPEG doesn't support alpha, which is what that error message is telling you. An easy fix would be to remove the 'a' channel from your image. There may be a clever way to do it without deserializing the data, but the easiest thing would be to use opencv to split the image channels, then merge back the r, g and b channels (leaving out a).

EDIT - [mixChannels](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20mixChannels%28const%20Mat%2A%20src%2C%20size_t%20nsrcs%2C%20Mat%2A%20dst%2C%20size_t%20ndsts%2C%20const%20int%2A%20fromTo%2C%20size_t%20npairs%29) will do it:
Something like this should work (taken from the example, not tested):

```
// Mat rgba = input image
Mat rgb( rgba.rows, rgba.cols, CV_8UC3 );

Mat out[] = { rgb };
int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2 };
mixChannels( &rgba, 1, out, 1, from_to, 3 );
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-06**:
Well, I was surprised too. :-) I have never used opencv... could you direct me to documentation or an example? Alternatively, is there a way to get what's on the Ogre Texture without an alpha channel?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-11-06**:
Edited my answer with an example. If there's a way for ogre to directly output an image without alpha, that's probably the way to go.